# How to force a mongod to become primary in a replica set?

Tags: mongodb

1) I have 3 mongodbs running in a replica set

```
mongod --fork --logpath a.log --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --port 27001 --dbpath data/z1 --replSet z
mongod --fork --logpath b.log --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --port 27002 --dbpath data/z2 --replSet z
mongod --fork --logpath c.log --smallfiles --oplogSize 50 --port 27003 --dbpath data/z3 --replSet z
```

2) Now 27001 and 27002 are down.

What do I need to do to make 27003 primary without restarting 27001 and 27002?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to reconfig the replica set: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/

Namely you have to actually go onto that member and run a rs.reconfig to remove those two dead members from the set since you have a majority of the members offline.

Comment: I'm doing a homework and there they give instruction that I need to use `rs.stepDown()`. But when I run rs.stepDown() it shows `{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not primary so can't step down" }`. How will I make 27003 primary using `rs.stepDown()`?

Comment: @Towhid you can't rs.stepdown steps down a member from primary

Comment: @Towhid if you run rs.stepdown on the other 2 members the third should elect itself

Comment: But other 2 members are down. So how should I run `rs.stepDown()` on them?

Comment: @Towhid no if they are actually down as in offline then no, then you need to reconfigure your set

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can do it.

#### The really easy way

Restart the other two instances after deleting the contents of their `dbpath`.

#### The easy, but insecure way

Assuming you can not get the other nodes back online (which reminds me a bit of a homework for M102)

```
replset:SECONDARY> oldConf = rs.conf()
[...]
replset:SECONDARY> conf = {
... 
... _id:oldConf._id,
... version: oldConf.version + 1,
... members: [ oldConf.members[2] ]}
[...]
replset:SECONDARY> rs.reconfig(conf,{force:true})
```

Note: Instead of putting 2 at `oldConf.members[2]`, you need to put in the position of the instance running on port 27013 in `oldConfig.members`, starting from 0. After you sent the `rs.reconfig` command, it may take a few seconds for the last node to come up as primary.

#### The sensible way

Get up two other nodes with the according `--replSet` parameter and use the procedure described above to add them by adding them to the members array of `conf`.

Comment: I am wondering since the documentation at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/reconfigure-replica-set-with-unavailable-members/ which defines the second approach does not state it is insecure why do you say it is?

Comment: Well, how many members do you have after doing that? Exactly 1. Which defies the purpose of a replica set. No data redundancy and no failover capabilities is what I call unsecure.